# Getting rid of the `lib` tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I noticed that there was a [lib](/questions/tagged/lib) tag on SO with on about 300 questions, most of which were using [lib](/questions/tagged/lib) as an excuse for the [library](/questions/tagged/library) tag that was removed as part of the great tag cleanup of 2012. Do you think we should remove this tag? Because if you ask me, it is pretty irrelevant. It should either be merged with [library](/questions/tagged/library), or gotten rid of.